# How to run on iOS 17 Device using Xcode 14.2

Tags: xcode, debugging, ios17

Xcode 15 beta does not come with Device support files for iOS 17. Any other way we would run iOS 17 devices on Xcode 14?

I expect to be able to deploy and debug iOS 17 apps on Xcode 14.

My app isn't migrated to the latest Xcode version so it's using Xcode 14.2

Comment: Seems like I found a solution to the problem. You can read more here: https://medium.com/p/d74cbc03da4d

Comment: I'd contend this is not a duplicate, as the [accepted answer on the linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76620301/2680007) seems to require Xcode 14.3, as several commenters ([now including myself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76412754/how-to-run-on-ios-17-device-using-xcode-14#comment135988977_76620301)) have noted. That difference is significant as Xcode dropped support for a major macOS version between versions 14.2 and 14.3.

Comment: What if you *only* have access to Xcode 14.2?