# Ios 17.1.1 development with XCode 14.2

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm rather android develop but got task to develop application on Iphone Xr with Ios 17.1.1. Unfortunately my laptop supports only OS Monterey so Xcode is 14.2 because it does not satisfy the requirements to download 15.x version. When I connect iphone to my laptop Xcode says that "Iphone - Could not locate device support files". Is there any way to make it work with my version of Xcode? I read that theoreticaly I should be able to download device support files and just copy paste them (however I didn't find where to download them yet), but another sources said that without 15.x I cannot develop apps on devices with Ios 17, so I'm a bit lost here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK it's impossible until you update XCode. Check the Apple Staff (Jason) comment on [the forum](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/730947?answerId=754878022#754878022).

> Copying files from a newer version of Xcode to an older version of Xcode for any purpose was never supported. That it worked for your needs was coincidental.

There is a repo for iOS device support on the earlier releases. You can take a look [here](https://github.com/iGhibli/iOS-DeviceSupport). However, it will not work on iOS 17 and above until now.

**Updated:** I've founded a workaround for XCode 14.3 from @Jonathan. You might want to try.

[How to run on iOS 17 Device using Xcode 14](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76412754/how-to-run-on-ios-17-device-using-xcode-14)

Comment: unfortunately my mac is too old for 14.3, maximum supported is 14.2. So close yet so far, I will try to downgrade ios to 16.2 and hope that there were no any breaking changes in newest ios which could blow the app. Anyway thanks for help!

Comment: Yeah. no worries.

Comment: @son does this work for iOS 17.1?

Comment: @raw I've not tried on 17.1.

Comment: How can you downgrade IOS to 16 ?

Comment: @BaniAkram unfortunately, you can't downgrade iOS.