# Xcode 14.3.1 hangs at "Attaching to (app name)" while running on Device iOS 17.1.2

Tags: ios, xcode, device, ios17

While Xcode 14 cannot run device iOS 17, i installed XCode 15 in order to my XCode 14 can run my iOS17 device, and now my XCode 14 can run device iOS 17 (Core Device) but while i run the program to device it stop at "Attaching to..."
I was follow suggestions in this thread:

[Xcode 4 hangs at "Attaching to (app name)"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5382968/xcode-4-hangs-at-attaching-to-app-name)

but it doesn't work, has anyone experienced?
*i use Ventura 13.6.1

and i have no problem when running to simulator

[image]

thank you

**edited**:
it happened after i tried this one
[How to run on iOS 17 Device using Xcode 14](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76412754/how-to-run-on-ios-17-device-using-xcode-14)

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76412754/how-to-run-on-ios-17-device-using-xcode-14) help?

Comment: my case happened after tried that one @son